# Prove that $\sum_{n\mathop=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^{1+i}}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am struggling with this analysis exercise:

> Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n\mathop=1}^\infty \dfrac 1 {n^{1+i}}$ is divergent but the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 1^+} \sum_{n\mathop=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^{t+i}}$ exists.

I know the first sum is not absolutely convergent because $\sum \frac 1 n$ diverges by the integral test. How how do I prove it is divergent? (i.e. not conditionally convergent). Would appreciate hints for the 2nd part too

Comment: $$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+i}} = \zeta(1+i)$$

Which does diverge for $i\leq 0$

Comment: For clarification, is $i$ the imaginary unit? or is it some index, or real number, that hasn't been mentioned somewhere?

Comment: You can start with Abel's sum formula on $$\sum_{n \leqslant x} 1\cdot \frac{1}{n^{1+i}}\,.$$

Comment: I believe there is some confusion in the first comment here. The series defining the zeta function actually diverges everywhere on line line $\mathrm{Re }(s) = 1$, even though the zeta function itself is defined everywhere on that line except at $s = 1$. This isn't particularly easy to prove, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $s \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$, Abel's sum formula applied to $a_n = 1$ and $f(x) = x^{-s}$ yields

\begin{align}
\sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{1}{n^s} &= \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^s} + s\int_1^x \frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^{s+1}}\,dt \\
&= \frac{x - \{x\}}{x^s} + s\int_1^x \frac{t - \{t\}}{t^{s+1}}\,dt \\
&= x^{1-s} + s\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t^s} - \frac{\{x\}}{x^s} - s\int_1^x \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}\,dt \\
&= x^{1-s} + \frac{s}{s-1}\bigl(1 - x^{1-s}\bigr) - \frac{\{x\}}{x^s} - s\int_1^x \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}\,dt \\
&= \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} + \frac{s}{s-1} - \frac{\{x\}}{x^s} - s\int_1^x \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}\,dt\,.
\end{align}

When $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$, we have $\{x\}\cdot x^{-s} \to 0$, and

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \int_1^x \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}\,dt$$

exists, so the convergence of the series depends on whether $x^{1-s}$ converges. Clearly that is the case only for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$. For $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$, the partial sums approach a limiting circle with radius $1/\operatorname{Im} s$. Hence the series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+i}}$$

diverges.

For $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, the above computation yields

$$\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} - s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}\,dt\,,$$

and the dominated convergence theorem shows the existence of

$$\lim_{t \to 1^+} \zeta(t+i) = 1 - i - (1+i)\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{2+i}}\,dt\,.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\lim_{t \to 1^+} \zeta(t+i) = 1 - i - (1+i)\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{2+i}}\,dt\,.$?

Comment: and I don't really get how the limit can exist. Surely if it is divergent at $1+i$ then as we go closer to it like $1.00001 +i$ it should tend to infinity. Are there simpler examples of this sort of thing happening?

Comment: You're right, I made a sign error. Thanks for spotting it. The limit $\lim\limits_{t\to 1^+} \zeta(t + i)$ exists since $\zeta$ is analytic - hence continuous - there. $\zeta$ is a meromorphic function on the entire plane, with only a single simple pole at $1$. Showing that takes a bit more work, but the meromorphic continuation with only a pole at $1$ can already be read off the second to last formula; the integral on the right hand side is defined and gives a holomorphic function for $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$. But the series converges only for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$. On the line

Comment: $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$ the divergence of the series isn't too bad, except for the point $s = 1$; at $s = 1+iy$ with $y\neq 0$ the partial sums are bounded and their averages converge to the value of $\zeta(1+iy)$ [the series is Cesàro summable there]. A simpler example of this sort of thing is Grandi's series for example, although in that example the divergence of the series already follows from the term test. We have $$\frac{1}{1+z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nz^n$$ for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, whence clearly $$\lim_{z\to 1^-}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^nz^n = \frac{1}{2}\,.$$

Comment: The series of the limits, $\sum (-1)^n$, diverges (the terms don't converge to $0$), but the partial sums are bounded (they alternate between $1$ and $0$), and the averages of the partial sums converge to the limit.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$\frac{1}{n^{1+i}} = \frac{\cos (\ln n) - i\sin (\ln n)}{n}.$$

Concentrating on the real part, we have for $m\in \mathbb N$

$$\tag 1 \sum_{e^{2\pi m}< n < e^{2\pi m+\pi/4}}\frac{\cos (\ln n)}{n} >\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sum_{e^{2\pi m}< n < e^{2\pi m+\pi/4}}\frac{1}{n}.$$

The last sum is approximately

$$\int_{e^{2\pi m}}^{e^{2\pi m}+\pi/4} \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

If the series $\sum 1/n^{1+i}$ converged, it's real part would converge, hence by the Cauchy crierion, the sums in $(1)$ would converge to $0$ as $m\to \infty.$ Since they don't,$\sum 1/n^{1+i}$ diverges.

Of course the "approximately" above needs to be examined, but all is well  and I'll leave it to you to make sure that's true.